# would anyone reply/share who is working on inventory and shipping solutions with Cardano?

Tags: smart-contract

would anyone reply/share who is working on inventory and shipping solutions with Cardano?

storage
shipping
automation
price quotes
samples
contracts
distribution

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is many more, but top of my head:

- We, at Five Binaries, have a customer that is using the [`cardano-oracle-node`](https://github.com/fivebinaries/cardano-metadata-oracle) to monitoring the supply chain of their products during shipping.
- Emurgo is working to port their [Traceability](https://emurgo-traceability.com/) Solution to Cardano.

Comment: very neat, thank you @Marek Mahut - StakeNuts!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late to the question, but recently Strait Brands announced they will use Cardano's blockchain to manage their supply chain.